# AmCharts - using "connect:false" by skipping null values for multi-line graph

Tags: amcharts

I want to connect the line graph (`"type": "serial"`) if there is any point in between the specified `minPeriod` variable.

e.g consider below data set

```
[
 {
  "date":"2017-07-15 01:01:01",
  "value1":"12",
  "value2":null
 },
 {
  "date":"2017-07-15 01:01:41",
  "value1":null,
  "value2":"20"
 },
 {
  "date":"2017-07-15 01:02:01",
  "value1":"12",
  "value2":null
 },
 {
  "date":"2017-07-15 01:02:41",
  "value1":null,
  "value2":"20"
 }
]
```

And in graph i am using

```
"connect":false
```

And

```
"gapPeriod":60
"minPeriod":"ss"
```

**Current Result:**
Current result is a graph with gaps for `value1` & `value2`

**Expected Result:**
To get a connected graph when ever `value1` has two points within `minPeriod*gapPeriod` timespan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any points with null/undefined values will create a gap when `connect` is set to false, regardless of whether the next point after that falls within the `gapPeriod`, as null/undefined values are considered as an explicit gap in your data. You want to set `connect` to true and enable [`forceGap`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#forceGap) in your graphs. Note that you'll likely want to adjust your gapPeriod as it the gap triggers when your data is >= to `minPeriod * gapPeriod`.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:01:01",
      "value1": "12",
    }, {
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:01:41",
      "value2": "20"
    }, {
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:02:01",
      "value1": "12",
    }, {
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:02:41",
      "value2": "20",
    }, {
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:03:51",
      "value1": "12",
      "value2": "20",
    }, {
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:04:31",
      "value1": "12",
      "value2": "20"
    },
    {
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:04:41",
      "value1": "12"
    }, {
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:04:51",
      "value1": "12"
    }, {
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:05:01",
      "value1": "12"
    }, {
      "date": "2017-07-15 01:05:11",
      "value1": "12",
      "value2": "20"
    }
  ],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "valueField": "value1",
    "bullet": "round",
    "gapPeriod": 61,
    "forceGap": true
  }, {
    "valueField": "value2",
    "bullet": "square",
    "gapPeriod": 61,
    "forceGap": true
  }],
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "ss"
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Changing the color to transparent will not display the line and will be displayed as a gap to any human eye.

Comment: I actually want to connect the points, whenever they are under minPeriod (no matter how many null/empty points are there in between).

Comment: Disregard everything I said before. I forgot about `forceGap`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: thats a bit closer to what i want.

Comment: please look at this fiddle code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Munaim/wwdwnqfw/1/). i want the last two red dots & aqua dots connected to their respective colors. The first 2 red dots must be dis-connected.

Comment: It's exactly what you want. Please re-read my answer. `connect: false` will *always* generate a gap when you have nulls, regardless of whether subsequent points after the null fall within minPeriod*gapPeriod. You have to remove that or set `connect: true` for `forceGap` to work properly with null values. [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wwdwnqfw/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I misunderstood the functionality of `connect`.
Thanks again. you saved my life :-)

Comment: **update** Another thing i did wrong was to use a downloaded version of amcharts which was not the latest version. 
Now i am using latest version. And its working perfect.